# ngb modal scroll to top of page

Tags: bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal, angular7

I'm using ngb modal in my Angular 7 application,
and while the modal is opened I need to scroll to the top of the modal when I do a specific action.

For example, there is a button in the bottom of the modal, once I click this button, I need the page to scroll to the top of the modal,

I tried to use

```
window.scrollTop = 0;
```

and

```
document.getElementsByClassName('custom-modal').scrollTop = 0;
```

and

```
document.getElementsByClassName('custom-modal').scrollTo({
  top: 0
})
```

but these solutions are not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways..
I used normal anchor: `<a name="top"></a>` and `<a class="btn btn-outline-dark" href="#top">scroll to top</a>`

See working example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nf8k31?file=app%2Fmodal-component.ts

> Disadvantage

URL gets changed in address bar

Another way is to create a link (or any other focusable object) and setFocus to it.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use this line

```
document.querySelector(".modal").scrollTo({top:0,behavior:'smooth'});
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! It would be great if you could add some clarification on how you created your code, what you took into account, and why your method would work. This will help both the author of the question and anyone else who reads your answer later.

Answer (score 0):

If the selected answer didnt convice you, here is my solution:

```
setTimeout(function (){
    document.querySelector( '.modal').scrollTo({top:0,behavior:'smooth'});
  }, 1000);
```

It doesnt work without the setTimeout, because the line get computed before the DOM is actually rendered. So the node doesnt exist yet.

Answer (score 0):

No `scrollTo` worked for me. Setting the `focus` on the other hand worked great! Here's my code

```
(document.querySelector(".form-control") as HTMLElement)!.focus();
```